# Sha256 hash of a zip file is different after git clone despite file contents not changing?

Tags: git, bash, zip

I have an issue whereby my automated build needs to zip the contents of a directory and Sha256sum the zip file. Easy enough.

However, the next run of the automated build needs to zip the same contents and Sha256sum the zip file in order to see whether any source code has changed.

Locally I've ran the following commands and generated a zip with the same hash each time (expected, as I haven't changed any of the code):

```
zip -q -r -X my-directory.zip my_directory/* --exclude ".gitignore" "requirements.txt" "*__pycache__/*" "*/\infrastructure/*"
sha256sum my-directory.zip | awk '{ print $1 }' > my-directory.zip.hash
cat my-directory.zip.hash
```

My build runs the same commands, but at the start of each run it is doing a checkout of the code from GitHub (as the build runs inside a docker container), which results in a different hash despite no code changes.

I've re-created the problem locally by deleting the repo and re-cloning.

Any ideas? I am thinking it's metadata or some sort but have tried different exclusion commands without luck.

Comment: I wouldn't expect different zip implementations to create a bytewise identical zip file.  It could be different compression settings or optimizations, file ordering, metadata...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current method looks error prone.
It relies on carefully constructed `--exclude` parameters,
and assumes no unexpected files.
That's very fragile.

A better way would be to use the `git archive` command to create the zip:

```
git archive HEAD -o my-directory.zip my_directory
```

This will disregard ignored files and other files not part of the repository.
This should guarantee consistent results.

Note however that `git archive` adds as comment the commit id.
If for some reason you want to remove that, you can do so by running this additional command:

```
zip -z my-directory.zip < /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the following git archive command now: `git archive HEAD --worktree-attributes -o my-archive.zip my-archive/`...but I'm still getting a different hash each time. I believe it's because the commit id is stored as a comment in the zip file. I've tried the following without success: `git archive HEAD^{tree} --worktree-attributes -o my-archive.zip my-archive/`. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlistairWebster I updated my answer to handle that use case

Answer (score 2):

Manually excluding patterns through `--exclude` doesn't seem to be reliable. Moreover you are not exluding the `.git` folder, that is not included into the zip file, but may in someway interfere with the hash.

You should configure properly your `.gitignore` files and use `git archive`. It's the best way to export files from a git repository.

Try to change your workflow in this way:

```
git archive HEAD -o project-archive.zip
sha256sum project-archive.zip | awk '{ print $1 }' > project-archive.zip.hash
```

and you'll get the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to build systems checking out files and the nature of a build is that the time of day has changed from the previous build, therefore atime, ctime, mtime have changed. Zip takes these modification times into the archive and they are the like they were from before after extraction. The files are the same but the timestamps in the archive are changing, therefore the archive is changing.

As part of my build (terraform lambda_function resource + jenkins) I have added a build step:

```
find . -exec touch -t 200010101010 {} +
```

This resets the access and modification times to the specified time instead of the time they were checked out or copied, and now I have a consistent checksum for the zip file.