# Sha256 hash of a zip file is different after git commit despite archive contents not changing?

Tags: git, bash, zip, gitattributes

I'm using git archive to export source code from a certain project folder `src` in a repository in order to calculate its combined sha256 hash like so:

```
git archive HEAD --worktree-attributes -o project-archive.zip src/
sha256sum project-archive.zip | awk '{ print $1 }' > project-archive.zip.hash
```

My git attributes file lives at the root of the project and looks a bit like so:

```
integration_tests/ export-ignore
src/unit_tests export-ignore
src/.* export-ignore
.git* export-ignore
.config.yml export-ignore
*.md export-ignore
```

This works well for calculating the hash of my source but I'm finding that modifications to project files that aren't being included in the archive, such as `.config.yml` and `integration_tests/foo.py` still modify the hash of the archive.

- There aren't any erroneous files in the archive itself.
- The sha256 hash of each of the `.py` files is unchanged.
- I only see these changes to the archive hash after I've commited the
  unrelated (unarchived) changes, so I believe this to be a git behaviour or a misunderstanding of the
  git attributes config on my part.

Presumably there is some git metadata on the source files that I don't know about that effects the archive hash?

Comment: It's not a duplicate question, I pulled that thread up on a search while I was putting this question together. It's name has the same structure as Alistair's question intentionally in order make the distinction clear.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46999767/1256452), though closely related, *is* somewhat different, so I re-opened this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `git archive` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html):

> ***git archive* behaves differently when given a tree ID versus when given a commit ID or tag ID.** In the first case the current time is used as the modification time of each file in the archive. In the latter case the commit time as recorded in the referenced commit object is used instead. **Additionally the commit ID** is stored in a global extended pax header if the tar format is used; it can be extracted using *git get-tar-commit-id*. In ZIP files it **is stored as a file comment**.

(all bold-face is mine).  Since you are supplying a commit ID via `HEAD`, that commit ID is stored in the zip archive as a file comment.  If you zip up two different commits that, after zipping, are the same except for this file comment hash ID, the overall checksum of the zip file will differ.  (Strip out the hash ID and the overall checksum of the zip files should match, except for the time-stamp issue below.)

One solution is obvious: supply the commit's tree ID rather than `HEAD`, e.g., use `HEAD^{tree}`.  Unfortunately that will immediately run you into the first non-bolded sentence: *the current time is used as the modification time of each file in the archive.*  So you'd have to set the computer clock back.  You could keep using `HEAD` literally, but then you'll get the new `HEAD` commit's time, rather than the previous `HEAD` commit's time, which leads right back to the same problem.

If there is some way to use an existing archive to re-set the time stamps on the new archive, or if you can compare the files shorn of time-stamps (and switch back the the old archive if all are identical) or compute a hash of the archive minus the time stamps, that would do the job.

There is no argument to `git archive` that will achieve what you want.  Modifying the Git source itself could allow you to specify a particular time-stamp; see [this region of the source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cb5918aa0d50f50e83787f65c2ddc3dcb10159fe/archive.c#L383-L410).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've changed my archive command to use `HEAD^{tree}` but unfortunately the hash is still different before and after a commit. You're comment was helpful though, the file comment on the archive will have been changing the hash. Since I don't care about the comment for my use case, I've tried to stripping the comment altogether using `zip -z my-directory.zip < /dev/null`. But I'm still seeing the same issue.

Comment: Ah, well, now the remaining problem is setting all the file times consistently. I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: Thanks that's good to know, I'll accept your answer. Multiple users pointed to git archive as the best solution for those wanting compare hashes on archives exported from a git repo on [Alistair's thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999767/sha256-hash-of-a-zip-file-is-different-after-git-clone-despite-file-contents-not) (which people are think I'm duplicating). That's what sent me down this particular rabbit hole.